# ADS1115 : measuring 5v voltages and powering with 3.3v

Tags: esp8266, i2c

I have a project where I need to measure 0 - 5 V. I’m using a ADS1115 to have a better precision, connected to a ESP12. Since the ESP is only 3.3 V tolerant and the ADS powered by 5 V (because it needs to be powered a the same voltage as the measured voltage), I put the two pull-up resistor of the I2C bus on 3.3 V.

Is it safe to operate like this?

Comment: I'd use a Bi-directional Logic Level Converter for I2C

Comment: esp8266 has no problem with 5 V I2C

Comment: Safe? Yes. Reliable? Not really. VIH is 3.5v at 5V VCC, and 3.3 is below that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your arrangement safe? Yes, perfectly.

Is your arrangement a good idea? No, it is not.

When the ADS1115 is run at 5V it needs at least 3.5V on the I2C bus to properly register a HIGH.

However you can pull up to 5v instead and you won't have a problem.  Not only is the ESP8266 tolerant of 5v, but that 5v is severely limited in current by the pull-up resistors, so even non tolerant inputs would have a hard time complaining. Worst case scenario, the ESP8266 pulls the bus down to maybe 3.8v (3.3v plus an ESD diode drop) which is fine for a logic high on the ADS1115.

However, if you want to do things properly, you really should use a proper I2C level translator.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought the ESP i2c bus was only 3.3 v tolerant. I don’t have enough space to put a logic converter (my pcb has be 4cm * 6cm)

Comment: So use a PCA9306 in DSBGA package then - 1.98 mm x 0.98 mm (can you even *see* that...?) I have used the X2SON version (1.40 mm x 1.00 mm) before, and that was, while tricky, actually possible to work with.